# How to use keyboard shortcuts to select a portion of waveform instead of mouse drag and drop?

Tags: c#

I am making a project where i am drawing waveform of an audio file in C#. Currently I am using mouse drag and drop for a part of waveform selection. But now i want that the waveform should also be selected by using following:
click at a point
press shift and click again on another point.
I dont have much knowledge about keyboard events. So need help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Control.ModifierKeys property to detect whether the Shift key is pressed.  Sample code:

```
private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
    if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift) SetSelectionEnd(e.X);
    else SetSelectionStart(e.X);
  }
}
```

Implementing the SetSelectionStart/End is up to you.

Comment: can u throw some light on implementation of SetSelectionStart/End. How I can use it for my purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyUp` event won't work for this, because although the `KeyEventArgs` argument for this event includes a `Shift` property that indicates whether or not the shift key is currently down, the event is not triggered when you *only* press the shift key (and not any other key).  The `KeyPress` event is also not triggered just by the shift key.

Fortunately, the `PreviewKeyDown` event is exactly what you need for this.  The `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` argument includes a `Shift` property (also `Control` for the ctrl key), and the event is fired when you just click the shift button.

Also, `PreviewKeyDown` is triggered on a `Form` regardless of whether that form's `KeyPreview` is set to true or not, which is handy.